# Problems updating Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, reboot

I started to update Ubuntu on line, without boot. But I interrupted the updating, because it was taking too long. So, now I can not access the graphics mode, ~tty7~. I need help, because I don't want to lose my archives. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting from a USB install medium, which you will have to prepare on another PC, yours or someone else's. At the graphics desktop, copy your data to a backup USB stick or USB hard disk drive (HDD), or any other action that backs up your data.

The quickest way to restore a working Ubuntu 16.04 may be to re-install from scratch. When you do this, consider making a separate partition for your data, such that your data and operating system (OS) are logically separated.

**Alternatively**, if you are lucky, at a terminal you can resume the update with this command, as root: `apt-get dist-upgrade`
which should resume a broken update. Get to the root terminal from the **grub** menu option **Advanced options for Ubuntu**, and then select **Ubuntu…(recovery mode)**. Then wait whilst the kernel boots and a menu is presented. Select **root** to get a root terminal (alternatively select **dpkg**, and follow the prompts). Get to **grub** by holding down the SHIFT key as the machine boots.

Sometimes `apt-get dist-upgrade` will need to be followed by:

`apt-get -f install`

`apt-get dist-upgrade`
which couplet may need to be repeated.

For future reference, install **synaptic** and use that to update. It's much easier to see what's going on!